# Subtract depletion And Limit for SUM

Tags: sql-server, loops, stored-procedures

First I'm using AdventureWork2019 as a reference

I have a query where I'm joining 5 Tables

```
USE [AdventureWorks2019]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Alter PROCEDURE dbo.TestLocation
@UseDate DateTime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT prodID
,SUM(PurchQty) AS TotalPurchase
,SUM(SalesQty) AS TotalSell
,StartDate
from (
SELECT DISTINCT  WO.ProductID AS prodID
, StartDate
,WO.OrderQty AS PurchQty
,SOD.OrderQty AS SalesQty
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD
LEFT JOIN Production.WorkOrderRouting WOR ON WOR.ProductID = SOD.ProductID

--LEFT JOIN Production.Location PL ON PL.LocationID = WOR.LocationID
--The above Join is the one for the locationID and it's working Fine
LEFT JOIN Production.WorkOrder WO ON WO.ProductID = SOD.ProductID
FULL OUTER JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail POD ON POD.ProductID = SOD.ProductID

WHERE  StartDate = @UseDate 
-- AND  PL.LocationID >= 10
) Test3
Group by prodID,StartDate
order by prodID ASC, StartDate

END
GO


EXEC TestLocation '2011-07-02 00:00:00.000'


Output(sample):

prodID  TotalPurc   TotalSell   StartDate
717         8         36    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000
730         9         47    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000
744         2         3     2011-07-02 00:00:00.000
747         12        21    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000
749         5         15    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000
761         16        138   2011-07-02 00:00:00.000
775         26        91    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000
777         12        78    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000
802         6         21    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000
804         40        60    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000
806         16        138   2011-07-02 00:00:00.000
807         24        23    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000
810         21        28    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000
811         6         21    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000
813         8         37    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000
817         21        28    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000
```

And another Table For LocationID (as a warehouse)

```
SELECT LocationID,CostRate,Availability 
FROM Production.Location
WHERE LocationID >= 10
order by CostRate ASC

LocationID  CostRate    Availability
50           12.25        120.00
60           12.25        120.00
30           14.50        120.00
40           15.75        120.00
45           18.00        80.00
10           22.50        96.00
20           25.00        108.00
```

What I want to do is to take each  `LoactionId` and `ProdID` and take `TotalPurc` to the location and decrement the quantity in the `Availability` column, each `TotalSell` will increment the Availability column. The max `Availability` quantity is 130.
If all locations have no Available quantity that is the Available is 0 for all locations then it will stop.

the above will work with the date specified as you can check the query and run it if you have
`AdventureWork2019`

simple output to check how I want the data to be:

```
prodID  TotalPurc   TotalSell   StartDate
    717         8         36    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000
    730         9         47    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000
    744         2         3     2011-07-02 00:00:00.000
    747         12        21    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000
    749         5         15    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000

LocationID  CostRate    Availability
50           12.25        120.00
60           12.25        120.00
30           14.50        120.00
40           15.75        120.00
45           18.00        80.00
10           22.50        96.00
20           25.00        108.00


Output :

     prodID TotalPurc   TotalSell   StartDate                  LocationID   Availability  Remaining 

        717         8         36    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000          50            130       18
        717         8         36    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000          60            130       8
        717         8         36    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000          30            128       0
--what happened above is that I took the (120-8) = 112 then 112+36 = 148 we only can use 130 then the remaining is 18 then we took the next `LocationID` with the least Cost (120+18 = 138 we can use 130 so we took the 8) and used it in the next `LocationID`
        730         9         47    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000          30            130      36                       
        730         9         47    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000          40            130      26
        730         9         47    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000          45            106      0
        744         2         3     2011-07-02 00:00:00.000          45            107      0
        747         12        21    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000          45            116      0
        749         5         15    2011-07-02 00:00:00.000          45            126      0

--the above is the same as the first 3 rows we subtract and add to the availability
```

The other condition is that if all locations reached 0 or 130 then stop

How can I do that in SQL Server? I tried using CTE but didn't work well with me and tried the cursor which I think is the best for this kind of thing but didn't achieve anything.

Thank you in advance

Edit :

```
ALTER FUNCTION GetStockMovment 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
@ForDate Datetime
)
  RETURNS @Sums TABLE (
        RemoveQTY Numeric(24, 7),
        ADDQTY Numeric(24, 7) 
    )
AS
BEGIN
Declare @WoSum Numeric(24, 7),
@SODSUM Numeric(24, 7),
@WORSum Numeric(24, 7),
@PODSum Numeric(24, 7)

select @SODSUM = SUM(SOD.OrderQty) from Sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH ON SOD.SalesOrderID = SOH.SalesOrderID
where SOH.OrderDate = @ForDate

select @WoSum = sum(orderQty) from Production.WorkOrder
where StartDate = @ForDate


select @PODSum = sum(POD.OrderQty) from Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail POD
INNER JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader POH ON POD.PurchaseOrderID = POH.PurchaseOrderID 
where POH.OrderDate = @ForDate


select @WoSum = sum(WO.OrderQty) from Production.WorkOrder WO
where WO.DueDate = @ForDate

INSERT INTO @Sums (RemoveQTY,ADDQTY)
SELECT isnull(@SODSUM,0) + isnull(@WORSum,0) , isnull(@PODSum,0) + isnull(@WoSum,0)
    RETURN;
END;
GO

select * from  dbo.GetStockMovment ('2014-05-26 00:00:00.000')
```

Output:

```
RemoveQTY   ADDQTY
189.0000000 5334.0000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use LAG or LEAD function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I tried using the `LEAD` function and it's working great for half the job, because I couldn't stop the function from the `locationID` that reached 0 or +130

Comment: Did you put these condition in where clause?

Comment: I changed the Query as a  whole to make it easier for me, I used a function to get me The sum of all The purchase and Sells and now I only need to make a Cursor somehow to make that work